How to create a project file in VS that gathers the output of multiple separate projects
I have several projects that will be compiled into a single nuget package. Based on a suggestion I got, I am trying to get this under the hood with NoTargets SDK. I have no experience with msbuild tasks. I have to gather the output of the projects, and copy those assemblies into the proper folder structure for the package. I am stuck at being unable to specify the output. Without the <AdditionalProperties> the projects are built, but in their respective output folders - and I have not figured out how I can get those locations without hardcoding (I use artifacts). Once I specify the output (no matter how), the build fails at not being able to find the output of the references of those projects (I have a helper project that is referenced by each of these. It is looking for that library in the destination folder I specify).
1>Target MyBuild:
1>  Target _GetProjectReferenceTargetFrameworkProperties:
1>  Target ResolveProjectReferences:
1>  Target ResolveAssemblyReferences:
1>    Primary reference "StandardHelpers".
1>        Could not find dependent files. Expected file "D:\Workspace\...\artifacts\bin\SDK\Debug\API\Helpers.dll" does not exist.

So for now, I am trying to get it to be built into the common folder, but maybe there is a much better approach.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.Build.NoTargets/3.7.0">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageId>$(AssemblyName)</PackageId>
    <Title>My package</Title>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="tools\*.ps1" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" Pack="True" PackagePath="" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="SetNuSpecProperties" BeforeTargets="GenerateNuspec">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <NuspecProperties>$(NuspecProperties);Version=$(Version);BaseOutputPath=$(OutputPath);PackageReleaseNotes=$(PackageReleaseNotes);configuration=$(Configuration);</NuspecProperties>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>    
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectToBuild Include="..\API\API.csproj">
      <AdditionalProperties>OutDir=$(BaseOutputPath)/$(Configuration)/API/</AdditionalProperties>
    </ProjectToBuild>
    <ProjectToBuild Include="..\Analyzers\Analyzers.csproj">
      <AdditionalProperties>OutDir=$(BaseOutputPath)/$(Configuration)/analyzer/</AdditionalProperties>
    </ProjectToBuild>
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <Target Name="MyBuild" AfterTargets="Build">
    <MSBuild 
        Projects="@(ProjectToBuild)" 
        Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Optimize=$(Optimize)" 
        >
    </MSBuild>
  </Target>
</Project>


Don't use the NoTargets project to build the other projects. Make the NoTargets project dependent on the API and Analyzers projects either by using ProjectReferences or by using a .sln file that sets the dependencies.

Do you build all three projects with one solution (.sln) file in one build? You say that you are using artifacts. Are you using Azure Pipelines?

This is a cover project for only two projects from the solution. Its sole purpose would be to gather everything to be packaged in a proper structure and do the packaging. I am now looking at NuGetizer as an alternative, but I am still missing pieces there too... No, I am not using Azure.

I commented on your other question and provided the link to the NoTargets project SDK. Azure Pipelines stores build outputs and calls those artifacts. You indicated that you are not using Azure Pipelines so your artifacts are not Azure Artifacts. What are the artifacts that you are using?

It's just the build property that puts all binaries structured in one folder instead of having them for each project separately. And this means that hard coding paths to the output assemblies is not really. Using Project refrerences don't result in the output of them to be in the same place. And I was unable to create a target that iterates and gathers everything needed. That's above my msbuild level for now. NzGetize however has the tools needed and does just what I wanted. Actually it does what you suggested at the other question, but without the need to tinker with the targets.

Did you check the  steps process of the build? Based on my test, i think if you use AdditionalProperties , the build will copy the referenced dll to your output directory, so  it can look for  that library in the destination folder  you specify.

@DouXu-MSFT Hello. Yes, building up a POC from scratch works. I don't know what break it. For now, I have abandoned this approach in favor of NuGetize, but I will have to do a meticulous check...

Hi @ZorgoZ, sure, besides, you can consider using common folder as you said earlier.

I followed your steps with AdditionalProperties but found the build works well. Please check the following steps:
My solution structure:
ConsoleApp1 solution
    - ConsoleApp1 project(no using NoTargets SDK.)
    - Helper project
    - ConsoleApp2 project(refers to Helper project)
    - ConsoleApp3 project(refers to Helper project)

1.Add a reference to the Helper project for both project 2 and  project 3.
<ProjectReference Include="..\Helpers\Help.csproj" />

2.Run the build and watch the output window:
2.1 create OutDir=$(BaseOutputPath)/$(Configuration)/API/ folder

2.2 create OutDir=$(BaseOutputPath)/$(Configuration)/analyzer/

2.3 copy help.dll to the specified output folder of  project 2.(e.g: API folder)

2.4 copy help.dll to the specified output folder of project 3.(e.g:analyzer folder)

If this doesn't work, please consider using common folder: set the Output path or Base output path to a folder to use for all projects in the solution.
Build to a common output directory
